# How to pull and host an image file pulled from DataGrab[EE module] instagram feed

Tags: file-manager, channel-images, datagrab

I am having trouble pulling images into my site using the DataGrab module. I am pulling in all the data just fine- including the image URL. But I need to take that url and pull the image to my own server. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy way of importing and manipulating remote images it's hard to beat [CE Image](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image). You might want to take a look at the `ce_image_remote_cache_time` [config setting](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/configuration) so that you can keep repeated remote requests to a minimum.